# How to replace occurrences by key

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a simple question about JavaScript,

Say I got the following string:

```
A)My Name B)My Name C)My Name
```

now I give to a function the key #1 expecting to replace the second occurrence of `My Name` inside that function and return:

```
A)My Name B) C)My Name
```

I haven't found the solution to this anywhere online so I'm asking.

Comment: It would make sense that some form of `STRING.replace()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace) would be useful.
By the way, how does the "KEY" come into play as this is a string and not an array? Do you mean "OCCURRENCE"?

Comment: Right, the key as if it were the occurrence match.

Comment: So, a `zero-based` index of the occurrence of the target "My Name"? Ok, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use split to separate the string into the parts, then join the before and after back together:

```
function removeNthMatch(input, removeString, removeIndex) {
    var splitString = input.split(removeString);
    result = splitString.slice(0, removeIndex + 1).join(removeString)
        + splitString.slice(removeIndex + 1).join(removeString);
}

input = "A)My Name B)My Name C)My Name";
removeString = "My Name";
removeIndex = 1;

console.log(removeNthMatch(input, removeString, removeIndex));
```